# Parsing HTML+RDFa in RDFLib

Tags: python, html-parsing, semantic-markup, rdflib, rdfa

RDFLib seems to [support](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) parsing RDFa data. Upon implementing a snippet to parse an RDFa-annotated HTML page, I run into this problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zonk/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rdflib/plugin.py", line 107, in get
    p = _plugins[(name, kind)]
KeyError: ('html', <class 'rdflib.parser.Parser'>)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basic-rdfa.py", line 7, in <module>
    g.parse("beatles.rdfa.html", format='html') 
  File "/home/zonk/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rdflib/graph.py", line 1209, in parse
    parser = plugin.get(format, Parser)()
  File "/home/zonk/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rdflib/plugin.py", line 109, in get
    raise PluginException("No plugin registered for (%s, %s)" % (name, kind))
rdflib.plugin.PluginException: No plugin registered for (html, <class 'rdflib.parser.Parser'>)
```

The following snippet is used:

```
from rdflib import Graph, plugin
g = Graph()
g.parse("beatles.rdfa.html", format='html') 

for subj, pred, obj in g:
    if(subj, pred, obj) not in g:
        raise Exception("Zonk!")

print(f"Graph g has {len(g)} statements.")
print(g.serialize(format="turtle"))
```

with the following dummy data:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>John Lennon</title>
</head>

<div vocab="http://schema.org/">
  <div typeof="Person">
    <link property="rdfa:copy" href="#lennon"/>
    <link property="rdfa:copy" href="#band"/>
  </div>
  <p resource="#lennon" typeof="rdfa:Pattern"> 
    Name: <span property="name">John Lennon</span>
  <p>
  <div resource="#band" typeof="rdfa:Pattern">
    <div property="band" typeof="MusicGroup">
      <link property="rdfa:copy" href="#beatles"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div resource="#beatles" typeof="rdfa:Pattern">
    <p>Band: <span property="name">The Beatles</span></p>
    <p>Size: <span property="size">4</span> players</p>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Indeed there is no line in `plugin.py` that registers any HTML data. How can I parse the rdfa-annotated data in this case?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but the documentation is out of date, we don't support RDFa parsing any more in the current RDFlib version (6.0.0) or the previous version (5.0.0)

To get RDFa support, you will have to use RDFlib 4.2.2 (https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/tree/4.2.2).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tested with RDFLib 4.2.2 and it works very well. Out of curiosity, is there any reason why RDFa support is dropped? Do you think that RDFa's implementation in the community is fading away, and is there any plan to bring RDFa back in the future RDFLib versions?

Comment: It was dropped due to the parser being buggy (https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/pull/828) and failing tests but this happened before I came to maintain RDFlib, so I don't have any context other than that PR. From reading the comments there and in the pyRDFa plugin (https://github.com/RDFLib/pyrdfa3) I think we _can_ still support RDFa, users just have to install the plugin. that plugin was working fine last year but clearly needs updating to work with RDFlib 6.0.0. If you are interested, I recommend putting in Issues (or even a PR!) to request the update to pyRDFA3.

Comment: Thank you @Nicholas Car for your answer and contributions to RDFLib. Unfortunately, I do not have the capacity to contribute codes and create a PR there for now, but an issue for this request has been submitted.

Comment: No worries @snowball147, glad you've flagged the Issue in the rdflib tracker. Hopefully we can sort this out in a patch release of 6.0.1 or similar.